# Having trouble extending a Backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am probably missing something easy or doing something wrong, but I am trying this and can't get it to fire the function...

```
var Home = Backbone.View.extend({
    indexAction: function() {
        console.log('index');
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log('render');
    }
});
Home.indexAction();
```

All I get is this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){return i.apply(this,arguments)}
>   has no method 'indexAction'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created the view type but did not create an instance.
You need to instantiate a view of type `Home` now:

```
var h = new Home();
h.indexAction();
```

Also, it might be better to rename Home as `HomeView`, so you know it's a view which can be instantiated.

```
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    indexAction: function() {
        console.log('index');
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log('render');
    }
});

var home = new HomeView();
```

[example on backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el)